# Is It Possible To Have Multiple Instances Of A Chart Control From A Single Data Source

Tags: vb.net, charts

Is there a way I can create a Chart Control that is always populated from the same data source, but I can place multiple instances of the control within my application?

So for example, say I had a Chart Control that displayed a count of all user's jobs for the week.  I pull the data from the database (on a timer control) and update the chart.  That's fine for a single instance.

However, is it possible to put the same Chart on a different form (even two other forms) that is automatically updated from the same data?  Rather than have to run a separate query on a separate timer for each Chart?

I am guessing a Class may be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to set it up correctly.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for any confusion with my post.  My example would be that I have a chart on a form that populates from a database.  I want to give users the ability to add a 'copy' of that chart to their dashboard if they want.  Therefore, I would need both charts to then update from the same data at the same time without running multiple queries.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A control can only be the child of one parent.
However if the clones should only be visible and not interactive you can use a little dirty workaround:

```
Public Class CloneChartControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

    'Add pictureboxes to this list that should show the data
    Public Clones As List(Of PictureBox)

    Private paintclones As Boolean = True
    Private oldbmp As Bitmap

    'Override the paint event
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        'Reasons not to paint the clones
        If paintclones = False Then Exit Sub
        If Clones Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.ClientRectangle.Width, Me.ClientRectangle.Height)

        'Disable the drawing of the clones while the chart's bitmap is drawn (recursiveness, will call OnPaint itself)
        paintclones = False
        Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Me.ClientRectangle)
        paintclones = True

        'Clean up the old image
        If oldbmp IsNot Nothing Then oldbmp.Dispose()
        oldbmp = bmp

        'Set the new image to all clone pictureboxes
        For Each p As PictureBox In Clones
            p.Image = bmp
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The idea is to draw the chart to a bitmap and set the bitmap as the image of pictureboxes that serve as clones. Whenever the chart is redrawn, the pictureboxes are renewed as well.

Unfortunately the chart does not seem to paint itself with the bounds given as a parameter in the `.DrawToBitmap` method. I first had a draft of the class that would create a new bitmap for each individual picturebox with the bounds of the picturebox but the chart would still only draw in its old size. Therefore I streamlined the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I can see your workaround should work, but I was thinking about creating 3 separate Chart controls (each on a separate form) that all update at the same time from the same data.  Or is that what you're saying isn't possible?

Comment: Oh I understood your question as the complete opposite (that you would want to avoid multiple chart controls in the first place) :-). That being said I don't think it would be a problem to just databind your data to all the chart controls. My first sentence means that you can't for example add the same chart object to Form1 andalso to Form2 at the same time. I don't have a lot of experience with databinding the chart control unfortunately so nothing guaranteed there.

Comment: Yes sorry, re-reading my post does sound like it could be interpreted different ways.  Sorry.  But yes, would like to populate separate Charts from the 1 single query and routine.  Would I use a class for that?